# Limiting a row set defined by a prefix in Google Cloud Bigtable

Tags: python, google-cloud-bigtable, bigtable

I was trying to do this in Python: I have multiple prefixes to query in Bigtable, but I only want the first result of each row set defined by a prefix. In essence, applying a limit of 1 for each row set, not for the entire scan.

Imagine you have the following records' row keys:

```
collection_1#item1#reversed_timestamp1
collection_1#item1#reversed_timestamp2
collection_1#item2#reversed_timestamp3
collection_1#item2#reversed_timestamp4
```

What if I want to retrieve just the latest entries for `collection_1#item1#` and `collection_1#item2#` at the same time?

The expected output should be the rows corresponding to :

```
collection_1#item1#reversed_timestamp1
collection_1#item2#reversed_timestamp3
```

Can this be done in Bigtable?
Thanks!

Comment: I'm not entirly understand. what the exact expected output in your example?

Comment: Can you share what did you try and what's your current output? what steps are you missing or failing?

Answer (score 0):

Is collection_1#item1#reversed_timestamp1 the rowkey or is reversed_timestamp1 actually a timestamp?

If it is not part of the rowkey you could use a filter like cells per column
https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/using-filters#cells-per-column-limit e.g.

```
rows = table.read_rows(filter_=row_filters.CellsColumnLimitFilter(2))
```

or cells per row
https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/using-filters#cells-per-row-limit e.g.

```
rows = table.read_rows(filter_=row_filters.CellsRowLimitFilter(2))
```

depending on how your data is laid out.

Comment: Please consider providing some source code to support explanation. Links have risk of going dead.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming each timestamp is a unique bigtable row, you can pass the limit to the readrows function:

```
prefix = "collection_1#item1#"
end_key = prefix[:1]+chr(ord(prefix[-1])+1)
row_set = RowSet()
row_set.add_row_range_from_keys(prefix.encode("utf-8"),end_key.encode("utf-8"))
rows = table.read_rows(row_set=row_set, limit=1)

prefix = "collection_1#item2#"
end_key = prefix[:1]+chr(ord(prefix[-1])+1)
row_set = RowSet()
row_set.add_row_range_from_keys(prefix.encode("utf-8"),end_key.encode("utf-8"))
rows = table.read_rows(row_set=row_set, limit=1)
```

If you want to do this on bigtable, you cannot query both item1 and item2 "at the same time".

Obviously we don't know your use case, but Bora is right that you should consider dropping the timestamp as part of the key and just pull it from the underlying cells. (thus making something like

```
filter_=row_filters.CellsRowLimitFilter(1)
```

correct) But this could create hot keys if timestamps are truly needed for your key granularity.